# Bilingual blog: WordPress, Tumblr, or Blogger?

Tags: blog, blogger, tumblr, wordpress, localization

I'm helping a Korean artist setup an internet blog to showcase her work. Her goal is to have her blog in both English and Korean.

Which of these platforms better supports bilingual posts: WordPress, Tumblr, or Blogger?

By better support I mean, which of these platforms will help avoid having ultimately to manage two different blogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/screenshots/) plugin to a Wordpress install.

Comment: Unfortunately, Korean <-> English translations rarely work (have no idea why). I already made peace with the fact that posts will have to be written twice, I'm just wondering how easy it is to centralize this process.

Comment: That plugin isn't an automatic translation. It provides two areas to fill in post information. Same post url, two different languages available.

Comment: Check out the [screenshots](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/screenshots/) from the plugin page for more information